# Center a div (horizontally and vertically) and don't stay in the middle if scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is centered horizontally and vertically. The problem is that if I scroll down, the div scrolls down too and stays in the center. How can I fix that it doesn't scrolls down?

Right now it it perfectly in the center (I use the margin because of the size of the picture (200px x 200px)). But it stays in the middle when scrolling down.

```css
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    }
```

```html
<image class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/fc0"></image>
```

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PjEWyq

Comment: Do you mean you want the image to be fixed relative to the viewport, or the page content? For the former, use `position: fixed`.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Exactly, thank you for your answer. Answer it and I will check it as the best answer ;-).

Comment: I am not seeing this, _"staying in the center of the screen"_ when using absolute positioning, https://jsfiddle.net/9yapb10e/. The only undesirable affect that I'm seeing is that content placed after the `img` would appear underneath the image instead of after it when scrolling. The image does indeed scroll out of view when the page is scrolled. The OP is describing the behavior of a fixed position element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the image in an element set to `height: 100vh; position: relative;` so the `img` will be positioned relatively to an element that matches the viewport (so the `img` will be in the center of the viewport), and as you scroll, the parent element will stay in place on the page and the image will stay positioned relative to it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 500vh;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="logo" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same behavior, but want your logo to always stay in the exact same location even as you scroll, change your position from absolute to fixed.

```
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    position: fixed;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    }
```

position: absolute means it's attach to its closest positioned ancestor

position: fixed attaches to the window itself

Comment: Absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to the closest positioned ancestor, this may or may not be the parent element of the absolute positioned element.

Comment: It still stays in the center when scrolling down. I just want to have the logo in the center of the page and if i scroll down dont scroll together in the center.